# Chrome extension schedule eventPage to get data from server

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developed a Chrome extension which get's data from the server (like rss reader) and because the data always updatable I want to get the data periodically so I set the files as below:

```
manifest.json:

"permissions": [
                "alarms",
                 ,
                 ,
                 ,
                 ],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "scripts/app/eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
```

---

```
eventPage.js :
var url = ".....=?";

function getJSONData() {
    $.getJSON(this.url, function (data) {
    var newItems = [];
    newItems = data.query.results.item;
    localStorage.setItem("savedJSONData", JSON.stringify(newItems));
});
}

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function (alarm) {
    if (alarm.name == 'getNewJobs') {
        getJSONData();
    }
});

// Create the alarm:
chrome.alarms.create('getNewJobs', {
    periodInMinutes: 30
});
```

After I get the new data from the server I store them in localStorage and in the popup I read from localStorage.

The problem is that the event page become inactive after 20 seconds or so, and the alarms doesn't fire.

Any suggestions,

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer: add chrome.alarms to pageEvent.js, even if the background was inactive it will run the alarms function when the alarms time comes.